# Restrict distribution of discount in the Magento admin reorder?

Tags: magento

I want to restrict the distribution of discount to particular category of items in the admin sales order. It would be great if I could know the class/file which is used here ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please elaborate more.  Are you trying to make a promotion only available to specific items within a category?

Comment: The moment a coupon code is applied in the admin, the discount is distributed amongst all the items. I am looking for the function which gets called in the grid Admin->Reorder. Thanks